# Leave DevTools open on tab change / page reload

Tags: microsoft-teams

So, turns out there is a way to open the console window from the Teams Client, hooray.

Right click -> DevTools -> Open DevTools (Select WebContents) -> Webview

Only problem? As soon as you change tab / reload a page, you have to repeat these steps. I really, really do not want to do this hundreds of times per day.

There, my question is this, is there a way to prevent that window from closing and simply updating depending on the tab that is currently selected?

Many thanks, fellow humans.

** EDIT **
Just to show that my tunnels are setup and the React app with the tabs starts properly in VSCode. I've used the MSTeams Toolkit VSCode extension to scafold the project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I run the app in Teams, I see my tabs content as expected.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why not just run Teams in a browser, for dev debugging?

Comment: I would also like to debug in the broswer, believe me... I just can't seem to get it work while I think my setup is fine. My ngrok tunnels are up for the tabs (and the bot, not shown here). When I sideload into Teams, the tabs show up properly with their content, VSCode tells me I'm supposed to be able to see my content at localhost:3000/search (tab name), but nothing shows up. I've updated OP with screenshots. If you have a suggestion, I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Don't be dumb like I was, use the web version of Teams instead of the desktop client. F12 will open the console for you without problems!